Between any two cities in a certain country, there are either direct flights or direct buses, but not both. Please prove or disprove some questions.
This is an exercise from my textbook called Graph Theory & Algorithm. As you can see,  between any two cities in a certain country, there is either a direct flight or a direct bus, but not both.
You may need to know two terminologies: firstly, "flight-transfer", it means that if you plan to travel from city A to city C by plane, but there isn't direct flight between city A and city C and there are direct flights respectively between A and B and between B and C. So you have to take a A-to-B flight firstly and then "flight-transfer" at city B, finally take a B-to-C flight to get to C. "bus-transfer" is similar.
We need to prove or disprove the following conclusions:

If there exists two cities travels between which cannot be achieved through at most one "flight-transfer", then travels between any two cities can be achieved through at most two "bus-transfer"s.
If there exists two cities travels between which cannot be achieved through at most two "flight-transfer"s, then travels between any two cities can be achieved through at most one "bus-transfer".
If for every city there is another city that cannot be reached by at most one “flight-transfer”, then there exists a city from which every other city can be reached by at most one "bus-transfer".
I don't know how to model this problem into a abstract mathematical problem concerning graph theory. Maybe, vertexes represent cities. And if there is a direct flight between two cities, then color the edge between them red. Meanwhile, if there is a direct bus between two cities, then color the edge blue. There can't be both red edge and blue edge between two vertexes because "there are either direct flights or direct buses, but not both". This graph is a special connected graph.  If the modelling is right, then how to solve?


This is not very clear. What are "flight-transfers" and "bus-transfers"? At first reading, it seems that if no two cities are connected by "flight-transfers", then all transfers must be "bus-transfers". But this would make the first problem trivial, so I must have it wrong!

Thank you for your feedback. Maybe I should modify the problem.

@TonyK I reedit the problem. Can you do me a favor?

Your modelling of the problem in graph-theoretic terms is completely correct. Cities are vertices, and the travel options can be represented as a 2-colouring of the edges of the complete graph on those vertices.

Let the vertices $V$ be the set of cities and consider the complete graph on $V$. Colour an edge between two cities blue if there is a direct bus, otherwise red (there is a direct flight).
1) If there exist $a,b\in V$ such that there is no red path between $a$ and $b$ of length $\leq 2$, show that for all $x,y\in V$ there is a blue path between $x$ and $y$ of length $\leq 3$.
Take $x,y\in V$. It cannot be the case that both $(x,a)$ and $(x,b)$ are red, otherwise there would be a red path of length $2$ between $a$ and $b$. So one of either $(x,a)$ and $(x,b)$ is blue. Same can be said of one of $(y,a)$ and $(y,b)$. Also $(a,b)$ must be blue for the same reason. So it is possible to construct a blue path between $x$ and $y$ using at most three edges.
2) If there exist $a,b\in V$ such that there is no red path between $a$ and $b$ of length $\leq 3$, show that for all $x,y\in V$ there is a blue path between $x$ and $y$ of length $\leq 2$.
This is simply the contrapositive of 1) (after exchanging the labels red and blue).
3) If for every $a\in V$ there exists $b\in V$ such that there is no red path between $a$ and $b$ of length $\leq 2$, show that there exists $x\in V$ such that for all $y\in V$ there is a blue path between $x$ and $y$ of length $\leq 2$.
I don't know why they specify "for every" $a$, as the result can be proven even if you have just one. Take this $a\in V$ and the respective $b\in V$ such that there is no red path between $a$ and $b$ of length $\leq 2$. Then for $y \in V$, either $(y,a)$ is blue or $(y,b)$ is blue (they can't both be red or this would be a red path from $a$ to $b$ of length $2$). Also $(a,b)$ must be blue. So there must be a blue path of length $\leq2$ between $a$ and $y$. I.e. the choice $x=a$ works.

Yeah, but how to solve this problem.

You only asked how to set up these questions as graph theory problems, so that's all I answered. If you need further help, please amend your question, including whatever attempts you've made.

OK, I will amend my question.

I modified the question. Can you do me a favor?

@advance I have edited my answer with the solutions.

Thank you so much for your help,. I have been spent much time to solve this problem. Your solutions are helpful.
